# Android limit view pager area

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is it possible to limit the area of the view pager. Example, only on the orange box in the picture.

[image]

Comment: just give a padding to your viewpager Item , or make a view pager only in that limit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend of your layout container of viewpager, it will be placed like a textview or other, with margin padding etc.